# Which iPhone is best for application development, 2G OR 3G?

Tags: iphone

I would like to test iPhone applications to test on device. I am in confusion on the version of iPhone which suits best for iPhone application development.

Can anyOne of you suggest me, is 2G OR 3G better? Its Urgent..

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be best off waiting for the iPhone 4, available in just two weeks. Purchasing an older model will restrict your ability to take advantage of all the features in the new version of the iPhone operating system, iOS4.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Response. i was interested in developing with 3G iPhone. is the iPhone 3GS or 3G best for development, let me know the basic price of each one, as i was unable to get their comparisions from Apple site.

Comment: Will the iOS4 run on iPhone 3GS/3G?

Comment: iOS4 will run on 3G and 3GS. Some features are not available on the 3G, like multitasking, because it doesn't have enough processing power. The 3G is also no longer available for purchase through Apple or AT&T, it has been discontinued. Why are you fixated on the 3G variants? What's wrong with the iPhone 4?

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz, nothing wrong with iPhone4. With the price factor,new in iPhone development, i have choosen 3GS. That's it.

Answer (score 5):

iPhone 4. If you want to make the best apps, that is. If you want to make backwards-compatible shite, try iPhone 2G. If you want something in between, try the iPhone 3GS, but skip the 3G. Whatever you decide, best of luck to you!

Comment: um, whats the difference between the 2G and 3G?  I'm fairly certain they are the same device, unless by 2G you mean the one prior to the 3G, which would in fact make it the original iphone

Comment: Thanks for your information. AS i have no time, i prefer to go with 3GS,but let me know the advantage of 3GS Over 3G. what is backwards-compatible shite feature.can you explain a-bit more?

Comment: @Jared,
2G is Original iPhone(1st Generation) +2nd Generation network(EDGE, Wi-Fi)
3G is iPhone 2nd Generation + 3rd Generation Internet Connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of app are you trying to develop?  As the iPhone 4 is released, you should be able to get an unlocked 3GS at a huge discount, and you will be able to test the iOS 4 and will have access to almost every feature except front-facing camera and gyroscope.

Comment: As i would like to develop apps with the all the features of iPhone. let me know the additional features of 3GS iPhone ,which Can't be done using 3G iPhone.

Comment: 3GS has video, camera focus, and a compass

||

4G vs 3GS - http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare-iphones/

||

3Gs vs 3G - http://www.engadget.com/2009/06/08/iphone-3g-vs-iphone-3g-s-the-tale-of-the-tape/

Comment: Thank You so much studiotentpole.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the original iPhone (I assume that this is what you meant by "2G") and the 3G are rather small:

- The 3G has 3G (UMTS) networking - so it is (or: may be) faster on the cellular network, but that shouldn't affect your app.
- The 3G has a different Bluetooth chip inside. AFAIK, you can use the Bluetooth peer-to-peer connectivity only on the 3G.

Both devices are slow compared to the 3GS, the iPad or the iPhone 4 and have only half the RAM. So, if your app should run on such a device, you should definitely test it on such hardware. But of course the best thing to do is test it on all *devices* and *software versions* it is supposed to run on. This includes the iPod touch and the iPad, try to find beta testers that have such devices.

Apart from that, keep in mind that iOS 4 (available on June 21 2010) won't be available for the original iPhone, so you are  be limited to developing software against the iPhone OS 3.x APIs if you want to target the 2G. If you would like to develop against iOS 4, the biggest user-facing change in there is multitasking, which you cannot test on the 3G. So for development, I would recommend at least a 3GS. This is the earliest iPhone that supports that API, so you will be able to test your app where. With the 3G you can use the iOS 4 APIs, but you cannot test multitasking features.

Of course, the iPhone 4 is to be released soon, so I would go for that. If you are on a budget or if you are locked into a contract with your cellular provider, you may consider the iPod touch 32GB or 64GB. Feature-wise, this is a 3GS without phone and camera, but with the same CPU (even a bit faster) and the same amount of RAM. Keep away from the 8GB iPod touch, however, this is still equivalent to the iPhone 3G.

Comment: Hi nd, Thanks for your Answer. What this UMTS meant for, as i was new for iPhone & its development. As i was using XCode 3.2.1, is it better to go with 3GS for supporting iOS4 features?

Comment: UMTS = Universal Mobile Telecommunications System - the worlds most predominant 3G mobile telephony standard, and the only 3G system supported by the iPhone 3G, 3GS and 4 (that's the reason why Verizon users cannot use it even if they imported one from abroad).
Just use the latest version of XCode, there will be a new one for iOS4, but I assume that will also support iPhone OS 3.x. The version of XCode shouldn't matter regardless of the iPhone you are using, it supports the both the 3G and the 3GS.